# Finding all rows in hierarchy from any position in the tree

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, common-table-expression

I have a table with a one to many relationship to keep track of what tickets are related to each other. A ticket can have any number of children and parents.

```
LNK_TIC_Parent    LNK_TIC_Child
--------------    ----------  
       1              2  
       1              3          
       4              3              
       4              5                        
       5              6


       1          4
   ___/ \___   __/ \__
  /         \ /       \
 2           3         5
                        \
                         6
```

I'm trying to select a tickets whole ancestry regardless of where in the tree you start from. So in this example, If you start from ticket 6, or ticket 3, or ticket 1, you will get all 5 rows returned. Order doesn't matter to me.

I'm new to CTE's, so bear with me, this is what I have right now:

```
WITH linktree AS (
    SELECT
       LNK_TIC_Parent,LNK_TIC_Child
    FROM TicketLinks
  WHERE LNK_TIC_Parent = 1 OR LNK_TIC_Child = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT C.LNK_TIC_Parent,C.LNK_TIC_Child
    FROM TicketLinks C
INNER JOIN linktree C2 ON C.LNK_TIC_Parent = C2.LNK_TIC_Child
)

SELECT * FROM linktree
```

This will return the direct descendants of ticket 1 only.
I tried adding another CTE and flipped the inner join to

```
ON C2.LNK_TIC_Child = C.LNK_TIC_Parent
```

But it didnt affect anything, I wasn't really sure where I should have put it anyways. I'm not even sure if this is in the scope of what CTEs can do.

Comment: From the data you posted this shouldn't return anything. You have no rows that meet either of the where predicates in your first query. (LNK_TIC_Parent = 38396 OR LNK_TIC_Child = 1)

Comment: Whoops, your right, that was a real value. Updated it.

Comment: Perhaps you need to look at your data a LOT closer. You have children 2 and 3 but there are no parents with those values. Look at Parent 1, It has two children listed but the children do not exist. Your sample data just doesn't match what you state should happen.

Comment: Both columns are just foreign keys associating two rows from a separate table, they exist elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got:

```
DECLARE @start INT = 3;
WITH [data] AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
       (1, 2),  
       (1, 3),          
       (4, 3),              
       (4, 5),                        
       (5, 6)
    ) AS x(parent, id)
), [going_up] AS (
    SELECT [data].[parent], [data].[id]
    FROM [data]
    WHERE [data].[id] = @start

    UNION ALL

    SELECT child.[parent], child.[id]
    FROM [going_up] AS [parent]
    JOIN [data] AS [child]
        ON child.[parent] = [parent].[id]
), [going_down] AS (
    SELECT [going_up].[parent] AS [id],
           NULL AS [parent]
    FROM [going_up]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT child.id, child.parent
    FROM data AS child
    JOIN [going_down] AS [parent]
        ON child.[parent] = [parent].[id]
)
SELECT * 
FROM [going_down]
```

Essentially, I broke it up into two different recursive queries; one that goes to all the way up the tree given a starting position and then, once those nodes are determined, goes all the way back down. You'll notice that there are duplicate IDs in the output. This is because there are multiple ways to get to some nodes (specifically, 3 in your sample data). The output shows each path. If that's not important to you, just do `select distinct(ID)…` and call it good.

Comment: Definitely on the right track, but doesn't work from different positions. if @start = 4 then it returns nothing. I added `OR [data].[parent] = @start` to take into account the starting point being parent-less but then the rows returned to not include the relationship between 1 and 3 or 1 and 2.

Comment: This is due to the fact that I've only represented the *relationships* in the data. That is, there is no member with an ID=4. Thus, `going_up` doesn't find it. If you add that into the data (as well as a row for ID = 1), you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "There is no member with an ID=4"

Comment: Instead of `select * from going_down`, run `select * from data where id = 4` to see what I mean.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. So what I did in my version is change going_up to 
    `SELECT [data].[parent], [data].[id]
    FROM [data]
    WHERE [data].[id] = start OR [data].parent =start`

and

    `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [going_down]`

to try and get the rows regardless of if start is only a parent or child.